# avahi-daemon withdraws IP address from my network interface

Tags: linux, arch-linux, dhcp, avahi, systemd-networkd

I am running an Arch Linux server in my local network. It has avahi-daemon running on it to advertise some services (like a print server).

It has happened for the second time now that my server was not reachable anymore. After some investigation, I found out that its IPv4 address had been removed from the network interface, with these messages in the logs:

```
Feb 04 22:36:34 edeltraud avahi-daemon[389]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.168.23 on enp0s25.
Feb 04 22:36:34 edeltraud avahi-daemon[389]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s25.IPv4 with address 192.168.168.23.
Feb 04 22:36:34 edeltraud avahi-daemon[389]: Interface enp0s25.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

The IP address is configured by DHCP using systemd-networkd. This is `/etc/systemd/network/enp0s25.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=enp0s25

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
IPForward=ipv4
DNS=85.214.20.141
DNS=213.73.91.35
DNS=2001:470:20::2

[DHCP]
UseDNS=false
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: WLAN? (wireless?)

Comment: No, cable._____

Comment: This is happening for me *24 hours* after DHCP lease is established.So timing might be a good indicator of root cause.

Answer (score 8):

The message "Withdrawing address record" doesn't mean avahi is removing the IP address, it just means that avahi *detected* that the IP address has been removed, and is changing its internal state in response.

In other words, you need to look further; this isn't avahi's fault.

Comment: Interesting. Right now I cannot see if there were any other interesting log messages around the time the problem occurred, as the journal doesn’t reach that far back. I will try to investigate more when the problem appears again.

Comment: The problem occurred again, but I cannot find any hints before the avahi message: http://pastebin.com/xVx9Mbxg

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, I'm having the same issue on a Hyper-V guest Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, and as you described, the first relevant message is that "withdrawing" message. I can refresh the address (dhclient) but unsure why it's going missing. Mine is pure default on the network setup (and the hyperV switch is shared with my own desktop which didn't have a blip).

Comment: Never found a solution to it, fixed it by switching to a static IP address.

Comment: Running into this with WLAN, did you ever figure out a solution ?