# avahi-daemon and ".local" domain issues

Tags: linux, dns, avahi

I have a **Ubuntu 16.04** based HTPC/Media Server that's running **24/7**. As far as I can remember using an official Ubuntu distro, I've always had issues with the **avahi-daemon**. The issue is pretty often discussed online. Some people decide to just delete daemon, however, I actually need it as I'm running a CUPS server and use Kodi as my AirPlay reciever.

### The issue

> **mDNS/DNS-SD is inherently incompatible with unicast DNS zones .local**. We strongly recommend not to use Avahi or ​nss-mdns in such a network setup. N.B.: nss-mdns is not typically bundled with Avahi and requires a separate download and install.
>   (avahi.org)

The symptoms are simple - after around 2-4 days of uptime the **network connection will go down** and this will be logged

```
Mar 17 18:33:27 15 avahi-daemon[1014]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.200 on enp3s0.
Mar 17 18:33:27 15 avahi-daemon[1014]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp3s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.200.
Mar 17 18:33:27 15 avahi-daemon[1014]: Interface enp3s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

The **network will go back up** without issues **if you physically reconnect** the Ethernet plug, or if you reconnect software-side.

### Possible solutions

There are three solutions listed on the official wiki, which has been non-functional since what appears to be *June 2016*, so I'm [providing a non-direct *archive.org* link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160608083415/http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal)

1.) Edit **/etc/nsswitch.conf** from

```
"hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4"
```

to

```
hosts: files dns mdns4
```

2.) Modify **/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf**

from

```
domain-name=.local
```

to

```
domain-name=alocal
```

3.) *"Ask the administrator to move the .local zone"* (as said on the wiki)

### What I did

The **first solution** did not appear to work for me - the daemon still works, however, the **network will go down the same way as before** (to be fair, on the wiki it *does say* "**Y**our **M**ileage **M**ay **V**ary")

The **second solution** causes the daemon to seemingly function properly (nothing wrong if you look at the logs) but the **iOS devices fail to "see" the machine** as a printer or an AirPlay reciever (as well as iTunes on my Windows machine)

The **third solution** is tricky, because I'm not well versed in the *"ins and outs"* of how a network is functioning; and I'm not sure I actually tried it. Here's what I mean: on my **Asus Router** running [Asuswrt-Merlin](https://asuswrt.lostrealm.ca/) I went into a settings subcategory /LAN/DHCP Server/Basic Config. There I set "**RT-AC68U's Domain Name**" as "lan" (a domain name I saw advised on the web, because it doesn't conflict with anything, unlike "local"). As far as I can understand, that's what "**moving the .local zone**" means. If this is in fact correct, than this solution does not work for me as well.

### Conclusion

So, what should I do? I've been battling with this problem for over 4 months now, and every answer online comes down to the those I've already tried; frankly, I'm completely lost.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This doesn't explain how you knew that avahi is the _cause_ of "the network going down", as opposed to this log message being a _symptom_.  See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271412/29483

Comment: @sourcejedi Searching symptoms "network going down randomly" point to Ubuntu related boards that reference this issue, and most people there mention avahi being the problem. [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339702/network-service-discovery-disabled-what-does-this-mean-for-me)

Comment: Wrong link, though I'm not going to argue about that. Nor about that search phrase not showing any such result for me, at least out of the first 10. From what you've written, I can only infer that you haven't tested removing avahi. Funny though, searching "Withdrawing address record" gives me several results about "network going down randomly" resolved as errors in hardware, none in avahi. 2) archive.org link in Q shows "No results found" for me.  3) which "does not work for me" applies to your third solution?, the implication is the result was the same as for #1, but it's not 100% clear.

Comment: AFAICT Barton's answer is written under the assumption that your third solution causes some error with avahi/MDNS/bonjour resolution/discovery only, and does not cause the "network [connection] going down" problem.  So it would be really good to clarify the symptoms you're seeing when you tried to apply the third solution!

Comment: In your travails, for example, I suspect you've seen the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/718653/avahi-daemon-repeatedly-registers-withdraws-address-record-causing-network-failu) in your travails.  Notice that the answer doesn't explicitly mention network failures, and the asker didn't accept the answer or say anything at all about what happened next.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, it's really valuable! To clarify, the "does not work for me" in the third solution means the result was the same as in the first solution, ergo, services using avahi work until the network fails. I automatically assumed that a hardware problem was not the case in this situation because the hardware itself is pretty recent (just recently hit a year since I built this machine), also, because the network failing once every 4 days, then being okay once I reconnect on the software side does not look like a hardware issue.

Comment: You are correct, I did not try removing avahi, I'm going to remove it now and try to use wireshark, like @barton-chittenden suggested

Comment: In my case this was caused by the routers access control list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried to change the "host-name" parameter in "avahi-daemon.conf" to something that's not the machines hostname, and I've been running 2 weeks without any issues.
Maybe this had to do with the machine also running samba and Windows using the ".local" domain for it's own purposes?

Comment: Windows / Samba do not assign a special meaning to ".local".  (It's possible to use `.`s in netbios for some purpose though).  avahi is enabled by default on ubuntu/fedora, and I've never seen a warning about running samba at the same time.  I can't imagine why avahi-daemon would include any code which _sets_ interface addresses or status. Thanks for coming back with your test result, I hope the setup keeps working from now on!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm so stuck on this.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. I have a home network with Macs, and they want avahi/bonjour and a .local domain to share properly.  My ISP provides a DSL router that provides private IP addresses (192.168.1.*) and gives a local domain (attlocal.net). However it also responds as an authority for a .local unicast domain - even though it doesn't really have one.  That is a no-no, but they do it anyway.  I was left with a network where Macs could discover and attach to other Macs, and Linux could see avahi services, but failed to connect to them.

**The symptoms:**  If your linux system is showing services but won't connect through nautilus. If DLNS services won't connect.  If `ping hostname.local` fails to resolve.  Finally if `dig local` gives an authority section result for your router/ISP.

**What works for me**:
create a file `/etc/mdns.allow` with the following two lines

```
    .local
    .local.
```

Then edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and in the line that starts with `hosts:` replace the item `mdns4_minimal` with `mdns4`.  The result for me looked like this:

```
hosts:     files mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Finally reboot or `sudo systemctl restart network`.  This has worked for me on Ubuntu 18 to 21 as well as Debian Stretch and Buster including on Raspberry Pi.  As a result I can see and attach to samba shares, AFP shares, and even SSH ports when browsing *Other Locations* in Files (nautilus) on Ubuntu.

**Why was it broken to begin with?**
`mdns_minimal` did not work, yet `mdns4` did.  That is not an expected outcome, and I got as far as trying to report a bug against `mdns_minimal` but then I found a clear answer why this is so at their GitHub site: https://github.com/lathiat/nss-mdns .  `mdns_minimal` will not resolve unless both domain is .local and also IPv4 is from the 169.254 self-config range.  It also will not look at an `/etc/mdns.allow` file.  So if you need to resolve .local and don't have self-config addresses you may need to replace it in `nsswitch.conf` as described above.

Comment: This solved the problem on our network, where MacOS hosts could *ssh* to Linux hosts but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

I think the third solution is the way to go when you have access to the router configuration. I would try setting the "RT-AC68U's Domain Name" to blank.

The next thing that I would do is run something like wireshark, and watch the packets sent and received by avahai-daemon, as well as any packets sent from and to any domain name ending in `.local` ... if something other than avahai is setting LAN domain names to `.local` you'll find it there.

It's also possible that the issue is something else entirely, and wireshark might tell you that as well.

If you're using Avahai entirely for the purpose of assigning domain names to machines on your network, you might consider using dnsmasq instead. You can run it off your RT-AC88U router, or from your Ubuntu box (In fact, it's probably already running on your ubuntu box, and you'll just need to tweak the config file).

[Documentation for setting up dnsmasq under Asus-Merlin](https://github.com/RMerl/asuswrt-merlin/wiki/Custom-domains-with-dnsmasq)

Comment: Downvoted for suggesting that Avahi has a bug such that the "incompatibility" causes it to set the network interface offline at random intervals, because this is a mis-conception that seems to be spreading, with no specific evidence sourced for it.

Comment: I'm using avahi to advertise the AirPlay and AirPrint service to Apple devices and software