# Why doesn't systemd-resolved use my local DNS server?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, bind, dig, systemd-resolved

I'm using a local BIND9 server to host some local dns records. When trying to dig for a local domain name I can't find it if I don't explicitly tell dig to use my local BIND9 server.

```
user@heimdal:~$ dig +short heimdal.lan.se
user@heimdal:~$ dig +short @192.168.1.7 heimdal.lan.se
192.168.1.2
```

Ubuntu 17.04 and systemd-resolved are used. This is the content of my /etc/resolved

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

And the output from systemd-resolve --status

```
Global
         DNS Servers: 192.168.1.7
                      192.168.1.1
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test
```

The DNS Servers section does seem to have rightfully configured 192.168.1.7 as the main DNS server (my local BIND9 instance). I can't understand why it's not used ... ?

Comment: I remember something along the lines of how `systemd` uses Google DNS as a fallback...

Comment: What is `systemd-resolve heimdal.lan.se` telling?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, changing my wired eth0 interface to be managed solved this issue for me.

Changing ifupdown to managed=true in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

Then restart NetworkManager

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

After this it works flawlessly..

This was not 100%. I also applied theses changes to try and kill resolver

```
sudo service resolvconf disable-updates
sudo update-rc.d resolvconf disable
sudo service resolvconf stop
```

Big thanks to this blog post regarding the subject:
https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2018/01/25/my-war-on-systemd-resolved/ (if unavailable use https://github.com/ohthehugemanatee/ohthehugemanatee.org/blob/main/content/blog/source/2018-01-25-my-war-on-systemd-resolved.markdown)

Lets pray this works.. This whole systemd-resolve business is just so ugly.

Comment: Late comment but `systemd-networkd` related another thing would be to check if the `eth0` or `enX` device has a `*.network` file in ` /lib/systemd/network/` see `info systemd-networkd` and `info systemd.network` and `info resolved.conf`

Comment: Just a simple restart of the NetworkManager service solved the issue that DNS update on my Wifi interface didn't reflect. I feared that I might have to restart but this worked.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is that your `systemd-resolved` service is configured correctly, but it never gets to see the request. The `.local` domain is [treated specially by systems running mDNS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/352237/avahi-daemon-and-local-domain-issues). `avahi-daemon`, which provides mDNS/DNS-SD services (aka "Bonjour" on Apple products) can be configured to take precedence over DNS during name resolution; it appears that Ubuntu does this.

There are a few options that you could choose from:

1. Rename your `.local` domain to something different (possibly `.internal` or `.lan`). This may be the easiest to do in practice because you just have to change a couple of things on your DNS server, and it works best with Avahi. I would recommend this method.
2. [Alter your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414277/cant-resolve-windows-domains-in-local-network) by putting the `dns` entry in front of the `mdns` entries.
3. [Alter Avahi's configuration](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/resolving-local-ubuntu-38861.html) to change the mDNS domain from `.local` to something else by editing `/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf` and changing (or adding) `domain-name=.something` (located in the `[server]` section). You'll need to do this on every computer that uses mDNS so they still work together.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I obfuscated the real domain here. It's not a .local domain. The top domain is actually .se. I will however follow up on your lead and check the content of nsswitch. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Thanks for this answer - could you point me in the right direction for how to "rename my `.local` domain"? Is there a command or interface for that?

Comment: Simply right! Thanks a lot. I had the same problem on MacOS with `.local` domains so I switched to `.lan`. But now I tried to use `automountfs` with hostnames and had no clue that here (without a domain ending) the exact same problem occures. Change my mountpoint to `server.lan` and everything is running fine !

Answer (score 0):

Seems this would be better as a comment, but not enough reputation....

Civing's self-answer was most along the lines of what I wanted.

I also had to add `dns=none` to the `[main]` section of `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, so it looks like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=none
```

I have just updated to xubuntu 18.04, from 14.04, and I have a LAN that's older than that, with many little adjustments accrued over the years.  So I want my DNS to do what I want (yes, I have purchased many copies of Cricket Lius's book over the years, starting with the second edition).

As an aside, I had previously been adding the DNS resolving information I want to see to the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

In a nutshell, once I had a working /etc/resolv.conf, as root:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

But now, I just edit /etc/resolv.conf directly, and it stays put.  Visitors to my LAN, who are using systemd/resolvconf, are SOOL.  They do not exist.

Reading `man 8 resolvconf` helped. A lot.  I did *not* follow the instructions for putting things where the ifup program could find them.  Mostly because there's a whole superstructure in the GUI that was already being ignored by whatever was done during the upgrade.  That seems to be a bigger issue (WTF, Ubuntu?).

So this is fugly, and there is still the issue that what I had (long ago) entered into the network control panel GUI was not being obeyed by the newly-upgraded system, but that's a totally different question, once I figure out how to ask it.

Answer (score 0):

For me, running a recently installed 18.04, I made the first change cited by @Civing:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

then, noticing that /etc/resolv.conf was always pointing stub-resolv.conf and that a reasonable resolv.conf with the proper LAN DNS server was being generated, changed the symlink:

```
/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

and then local all hostnames resolved via ping.

It remains to be seen how long this keeps working.

When I initially installed, wireless network setup failed, and I can't help but wonder if the installation left /etc/resolv.conf in this initial state.

So, one suggestion is to look at what resolved is generating; you may have a working basis already.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ubuntu 18, and I'm more used to debian and centOS.  Cue confusion.

resolve.conf said it's using systemd-resolved ok...

systemd shows global and per-link settings ok...

research shows that may mean it's using netplan

So, open up /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml, and it says...renderer: NetworkManager

Turns out NetworkManager is in the gui, and a way to enable per-link settings.
But...you can install nmcli and configure this sucker on the command line....

I hope this helped someone.

Comment: It would maybe help a lot more if you could elaborate if `renderer: NetworkManager` is what it should be or if not what it should be changed to ;)

Comment: You could change it to networkd. But instead, I used nmcli to modify the settings of NetworkManager. My goal was not to change the system setup but find where dns settings could be changed.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for your reply!