# Domain names ending with .local not resolved

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved, mdns, resolvconf

I have a strange problem resolving .local hosts on my linux (ubuntu) desktop.
(I noticed that because my printer stops working. I figured out that the IP address of the printer is resolved using mdns which isn't working.)
Then I tried to ping an other computer. The result is:

```
ping: zoe.local: Name or service not known
```

avahi-browse is able to resolve the IP address

```
= enp0s31f6 IPv4 zoe [xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx]                       Workstation          local
   hostname = [zoe.local]
   address = [192.168.3.221]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
```

Then I checked the content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. It looks normal.

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat systemd
group:          compat systemd
shadow:         compat
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname mymachines
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

/etc/resolv.conf is a symlink to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf and the content seems to be standard:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search intern
```

libnss-mdns is also installed.

On my second machine in the same network the .local address reolution works perfectly. Then I compared the two ping commands with strace. I figured out that the result of the systemd-resolved is different. I captured the traffic of the loopback interface. The interesting thing is that the systemd-resolvd reports a SOA for the .local domain. In the next step the address resolution asks my router for the .local address. This causes the error above.

The wireshark capture shows:

```
1   0.000000000 127.0.0.1   127.0.0.53  DNS 65  Standard query 0x70d2 SOA local
2   0.001437    127.0.0.53  127.0.0.1   DNS 113 Standard query response 0x459c SOA local SOA router.intern
```

The my second machine the local systemd resolver doesn't report a SOA and the mdns address resolutions works well.

```
1   0.000000000 127.0.0.1   127.0.0.53  DNS 65  Standard query 0x70d2 SOA local
2   0.027250385 127.0.0.53  127.0.0.1   DNS 65  Standard query response 0x70d2 No such name SOA local
```

I have tried to flush the dns cache with `systemd-resolve --flush-caches` but it makes no differences.

It seems that the systemd-resolvd behaves very strange. Does anyone know whats going wrong here? Why answers the systemd-resolved with a SOA?

`systemd-resolve --status` looks good to me:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNS Domain: intern              
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                

Link 6 (vmnet8)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 5 (vmnet1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 4 (virbr0-nic)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 3 (virbr0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no  

Link 2 (enp0s31f6)
      Current Scopes: DNS                     
DefaultRoute setting: yes                     
       LLMNR setting: yes                     
MulticastDNS setting: no                      
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                      
      DNSSEC setting: no                      
    DNSSEC supported: no                      
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.3.1             
         DNS Servers: 192.168.3.1             
                      fe80::2a0:57ff:fe24:94c9
          DNS Domain: ~.                      
                      intern
```

Comment: Quite possibly a duplicate of [avahi-daemon and ".local" domain issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/634695) and/or [I can resolve a \*.local domain, ping the IP, but I can't ping this domain](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/647106) as it uses a _very similar_ answer to answers found to these questions.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

I found the following issue: https://github.com/lathiat/nss-mdns/issues/75

My router / ISP provides a SOA for the .local domain. The `unicast SOA heuristic` prevents from mdns resolving. I added `/etc/mdns.allow` with the following content:

```
.local.
.local
```

After switching to mdns4 instead of mdns4_minimal it works.

```
hosts:          files mdns4 [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname mymachines
```